# GCP Deployment Manager: Templates automcomplete/validation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

It's hard to navigate through all the docs given the number of services and properties involved in creating templates for the Deployment Manager. I wonder if there is a solution for that. I imagine that code editors like VS-Code are supposed to have autocomplete, maybe GCP provides something to help write templates faster.

Comment: Console shell have autocomplete but what do you exactly mean by automcomplete in Deployment Manager? In `Cloud Shell Editor`? Autocomplete when you would create templates?

Comment: @PjoterS I'm sure he means the last option: autocomplete when you are editing the templates. I have not found any JSON Schema for that. Schema Store has one for AWS Cloud Formation, but not for GCP Deployment Manager.

Comment: interesting. All the schemas are available here: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types

Comment: @stkvtflw honestly I doubt that Cloud shell editor have this option. Those schemas will help you or provide workaround?

Answer (score -1):

I doubt that there is something like autocomplete for Deployment Manager Templates.

`Deployment Manager` accepts both `Jinja` and `Python` syntax in the same configuration as mentioned in
[Template Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template#template_syntax)

> Deployment Manager accepts both Jinja and Python templates. You can import templates in both languages in the same configuration.

As OP `stkvtflw` mentioned, there is already documentation which covers all schemas in GCP Documentation - [Supported resource types](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types).

Additional samples can be found in `Github repository`, which can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2)

Regarding the possibility to use `autocomplete` in `Deployment Manager`, there is a still opened Github `Feature Request` to [Add support for auto completion of configuration files](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2757).

In addition to that, you could file a `Feature Request` in Google [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).